# Sonata Admin - Order List by calculated value

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Is there a way to have a column in a Sonata Admin list that uses a calculated value as the sort by ??

Something like this: ( this does NOT work )

```
    $mapper->add('stock', null, [
        'sortable' => '(stock.real - stock.inCustomerOrder)',
    ]);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding twig tags ? `'sortable' => '{{ stock.real - stock.inCustomerOrder }}'` Not sure that works, and this would be a terrible hack anyway

Comment: That does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 2 values are coming from the same table, what about adding a real column? (and with a Doctrine listener, you could keep it synchronized when entity have changed).

Or, you could override the query generated by Sonata, from the documentation here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#customizing-the-query-used-to-generate-the-list

Comment: You can set a condition / where clause in the custom query. But you cannot sort by a derived or calculated value.

Comment: Didnt try, but you should be able to rewrite the query completely, the $query is Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Datagrid\ProxyQuery, a wrapper of the Doctrine QueryBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Since sorting is based on database queries, you can not sort by virtual/calculated fields.